# Какой контекст следует использовать в fragment?

Tags: java, android

Возникла проблема с использованием контекста в fragment:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
```

Контекст вызывает ошибку NullPointerException, `this` не работает в принципе. Какое контекст следует использовать в fragment? Спасибо заранее!

Полный код fragment'a:

```
package com.example.beecalc.ui.gallery;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.method.MovementMethod;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import com.example.beecalc.R;
import java.lang.String;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
CalendarView cal;
ArrayList dates = new ArrayList();
int[] decline = {0, 4, 9, 10, 14, 15, 23, 30};
TextView[] text = new TextView[8];
TextView[] tv = new TextView[8];
private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
String sname = "";
public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                         final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    galleryViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery);
    textView.setText("Дата закладки яиц:");
    text[0]= root.findViewById(R.id.v1);
    text[1]= root.findViewById(R.id.v2);
    text[2]= root.findViewById(R.id.v3);
    text[3]= root.findViewById(R.id.v4);
    text[4]= root.findViewById(R.id.v5);
    text[5]= root.findViewById(R.id.v6);
    text[6]= root.findViewById(R.id.v7);
    text[7]= root.findViewById(R.id.v8);

    tv[0]= root.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv[1]= root.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv[2]= root.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    tv[3]= root.findViewById(R.id.tv4);
    tv[4]= root.findViewById(R.id.tv5);
    tv[5]= root.findViewById(R.id.tv6);
    tv[6]= root.findViewById(R.id.tv7);
    tv[7]= root.findViewById(R.id.tv8);

    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        tv[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        text[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    final CalendarView c = root.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    c.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day) {
            String a = String.format("%02d.%02d.%04d", day, month + 1, year);
            dates.add(a);
            text[0].setText((String)dates.get(0));
            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            tv[0].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text[0].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for (int i=1; i<decline.length; i++) {
                tv[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                text[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                try {
                    c.setTime(sdf.parse(a));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, decline[i]);
                String output = sdf1.format(c.getTime());
                dates.add(output);
                text[i].setText(""+dates.get(i));

            }
            dates.clear();
        }




    });
    return root;
}
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
final EditText edit = new EditText(getActivity());
public void save(View view) {
    builder.setTitle("Сохранить")
            .setMessage("Пожалуйста, введите название файла для сохранения")
            .setView(edit)
            .setPositiveButton("Cохранить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    sname = edit.getText().toString();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                }
            });
    builder.show();
}
```

}

Comment: getActivity() подойдёт

Comment: @Komdosh , пробовал, тоже NullPointer ...

Comment: значит у вас что-то не так в целом :) Приведите полное описание как вы создаёте и используете фрагмент

Comment: @Komdosh, добавил полный код fragment, если Вы это имели в виду)

Comment: ага, только ещё метод, где вы его вызываете добавьте

Comment: @Komdosh, вызываю в методе OnCreate, чуть выше метода save, который находится в самом конце

Comment: не, я имею ввиду фрагмент где вы вызываете

Comment: @Komdosh, сам xml?

Comment: а, вы его через xml создаёте, тогда ок

Comment: вообще это странно, а приведите тогда описание ошибки, точно на строке new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()); падает?

Comment: @Komdosh, извините, в студии я недавно, возможно не понял вашего предыдущего вопроса.. Я подумал, что вам нужно описание кнопки, по которой происходит вызов метода save... Что касаемо ошибки, то да, NullPointerException на этой строке...

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:227)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:472)
        at com.example.beecalc.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment.<init>(GalleryFragment.java:105)`

Comment: блин, только сейчас заметил, вы дёргаете context в классе, а не в методе, дело в том, что когда создаётся объект класса, многие поля (context в частности) ещё не проинициализированы, вам нужно вызывать new AlertDialog.Builder в onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте записать getContext() в переменную в OnCreateView() а потом в вашем onViewCreated() использовать её.

Вот пример как это сделать:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54978893/12695243